# Phantom equals sign in aligned equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, pdftex

When typing out long equations, I like to split everything up into separate lines and start each one off with an equals sign. How do I hide the first equals sign while keeping the layout exactly the same? I tried wrapping it with `\phantom`, but that oddly decreases the horizontal offset of the first line:

> [image]

Here's the source for the above picture:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &\phantom{=} x^2 - 1 \\
        &= (x - 1) (x + 1) \\           &= 7
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Moving the ampersands to the other side of the equals signs sort of works, but it makes the equals signs too close to the equations:

> [image]

Comment: @ILiketoCode But the answer is with no `\phantom`. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your first attempt almost had it: you just need to write `\phantom{{}={}}` instead of `\phantom{=}`.

In the picture below, I've inserted `X`s at the start of each line to help ascertain visually that the alignment is working.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &\phantom{{}={}} x^2 - 1 \\
        &= (x - 1) (x + 1) \\
        &= 7
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you explain why I need extra {}?

Comment: @kww - The two pairs of `{}` are "empty math atoms". Their presence informs TeX that `=` is supposed to be treated as an object of type "mathrel" (math-relational operator) rather than of type "mathord" (math-ordinary). This has important consequences for the amount of whitespace that's inserted on either side of the equal sign. Try the code with and without the two pairs of `{}` -- you'll notice a big difference!

Comment: You can also use `\mathrel{\phantom{=}}` if you like to be explicit. I usually define an `\equad` command which does just that.

Comment: `\mathrel{\phantom{=}}` is more versatile, because `\phantom{{}={}} -A` and `\phantom{{}={}} \sum` have incorrect spacings.

Answer (score 4):

Rather ugly, but if you like...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        {}& x^2 - 1 \\
        ={} &(x - 1) (x + 1) \\
        ={} &7
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do the `{}`s do?

Comment: They make an additional argument, so `=` can behave as in between two arguments, i.e. with proper spacing. The first one is unnecessary.

Comment: @Blender: It places "something" (an empty group). In this particular case it allows `=` to act like a binary relation, and therefore have the appropriate `\mathrel` spacing around it.